# Convert a memcpy char[] into a string

Tags: c++

I need to:

1. convert a uint64 memcpy'd char[] into string
2. pass to another part of the application
3. then convert the string into back into uint64 via memcpy

I have the serialized char[]. However when I turn it into a string the contents change:

```
    uint64_t a = 6232222100000000000;
    char key[sizeof(a)] = {0};
    std::memcpy(key, &a, sizeof(uint64_t));

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(uint64_t); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << std::bitset<8>(key[i]);
    }
    std::cout << "\n";


    std::string out(key);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(uint64_t); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << std::bitset<8>(out[i]);
    }
```

The values outputted are:

```
0000000011001000110101101110111111111010010011000111110100000000
0000000000011101010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong

Comment: C tag removed. Please note that C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: won't make that mistake again!

Comment: If this is an assignment, it is a pretty bad one... basically you shouldn’t convert an int pointer or array into another size and use it as another type; even if you avoid breaking aliasing and conversion rules it will be smelly.

Comment: There's no guarantee that `key` is a valid string, and if the data contains a `\0` it will terminate early, and if it doesn't it will access data out of bounds of `key`. If you want to put the data into an `std` something, `std::array` or `std::vector` are better choices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the bytes in the `uint64_t` are 0, so they will be treated as null terminators when you convert the `char[]` array to a `std::string` using the `std::string(const char*)` constructor that expects a pointer to a null-terminated character array as input. Thus, it will truncate your `char` data.

Then your `for` loop after the conversion goes out of bounds of the converted `std::string`, causing *undefined behavior*.

To avoid this, you need to specify the full size of the `char[]` array during the conversion to `std::string`:

```cpp
std::string out(key, sizeof(key));
```

Comment: For context, this is a search system that uses strings to deserialize query id keys into a custom key object. I'm adding a feature that does expansion of some keys into other mapped keys. Will accept when SO lets me

Comment: If you have a c++20 compiler you could use `key = std::bitcast<decltype(key)>(a);`
Also a reinterpret cast, or a union can do the job, but both are a bit dirty.